# Calculating the probability of taking at least each route once from the three possible routes

Tags: probability

Please explain how to approach this problem. I have the answer, but I do not understand how you deduce the answer.

Each morning, Fred makes a random choice of one of three routes to take to work. After $n$ trips, $(n > 0)$, what is the probability that he has traveled each route at least once?

Hint: Use inclusion-exclusion to calculate the probability of the complementary event.

The answer is : $1 − 3\cdot \frac{2}{3}^n + 3 \cdot \frac{1}{3}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Call the routes A, B, and C. Let $p$ be the probability that there is a route he has not taken. Then the required probability is $1-p$.

The probability he has never taken Route A is $(2/3)^n$. Similarly, the probability he has never taken Route B is $(2/3)^n$, and the probability he has never taken Route C is $(2/3)^n$.

If we add these two probabilities, we get $3(2/3)^n$. However, this sum double counts the probability he has never taken Routes B or C, that is, that he has always taken Route A. The sum also double counts the probability he has never taken Routes A or B, and also the probability he has never taken Routes A or C. Each of these events has probability $(1/3)^n$. So from the sum $3(2/3)^n$ we must subtract $3(1/3)^n$ to find the probability $p$ he has missed at least one route.

**Or else equivalently** the routes he takes over the $n$ days can be represented by a word of length $n$ over the alphabet A, B, C. All such words are equally likely. We want to count the **favourable** words, the words that contain at least one each of A, B, and C. Instead we count the **bad** words, the words that miss at least one of A, B, C. The counting is done by Inclusion/Exclusion.

There are $2^n$ words that miss A, that is, $2^n$ words over the alphabet B, C. There are also $2^n$ words that miss B, and $2^n$ that miss C.

If we find the sum $2^n+2^n+2^n$, we will have double-counted the words that miss both A and B, that is, the words that only contain C. There is one such word. We will also have double-counted the word with all B's, and the word with all A's. Thus the number of bad words is $3(2^n)-3$.

It follows that the probability of a bad word is $$\frac{3(2^n)-3}{3^n},$$
and therefore our required probability is
$$1-\frac{3(2^n)-3}{3^n}.$$
This simplifies to the answer given in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

At the first trip he picks one of the 3 routes. Say he pick that route for N successive times until he picks another route. The probability that this will happen, is $(\frac{1}{3})^{N-1}$.( ie before he switches route. ) Now, say he does swap route at the $N+1$ trip. Say he picks another route, B. Now for all the following trips, say total trips n, he must pick one of the two.

The probability of this happening is: $(\frac{1}{3})^{N-1}(\frac{2}{3})^{n-N}$
Sum over all N: $\frac{3}{2}(\frac{1}{2})^{N}(\frac{2}{3})^{n}$ (Geometric series). So we get $3*((\frac{2}{3})^{n}-(\frac{1}{3})^{n})$

Comment: yea this needs a little bit more work, but if it helps it helps

Answer (score 0):

It might help to see the inclusion exclusion method explicitly.
You want the complement of "there is at least one route he doesn't take". Let $A$ stand for the event "doesn't take route a" etc. Then
$P$(there is at least one route he doesn't take) is $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)-P(B\cap C)-P(C\cap A) + P(A\cap B\cap C)$ and  $P(A)=(\frac{2}{3})^n$, $P(A\cap B)=(\frac{1}{3})^n$ and $P(A\cap B\cap C) = 0$.